# Need help getting the true ICRF coordinates of SOHO using Horizons

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, skyfield, python, soho

In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/15429/12102) I calculated the approximate angular separation between Mercury and the Sun as seen by the [SOHO satellite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_and_Heliospheric_Observatory) using [Skyfield](http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/)'s method of `.ecliptic_position()` because I couldn't get true ICRF coordinates for SOHO from the [Horizons web interface](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi).

Is there a way I can get ICRF coordinates for SOHO that haven't been rotated into the ecliptic?

> Coordinate system description:
> Ecliptic and Mean Equinox of Reference Epoch
>
> Reference epoch: J2000.0
>
> xy-plane: plane of the Earth's orbit at the reference epoch
>
> x-axis  : out along ascending node of instantaneous plane of the Earth's orbit and the Earth's mean equator at the reference epoch
>
> z-axis  : perpendicular to the xy-plane in the directional (+ or -) sense of Earth's north pole at the reference epoch.

You can see that x,y are indeed a circle, but z is just +/- a tiny fraction of an au - basically the vertical component of the halo orbit. That's confirmed by the 6-month periodicity.

*So how can I get true ICRF coordinates instead of these coordinates flattened to the particular plane the earth moves in at epoch*?

**Horizons web interface setup:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the "Table Settings". You want to select

```
reference plane: Earth mean equator and equinox of reference epoch
reference system: ICRF/J2000.0
```

Comment: OK I see - great! So `Earth mean equator and equinox of reference epoch = J2000.0` would be the same as saying "ICRF coordinates"? I'm trying to learn the vocabulary here. Is "ICRF coordinates" unambiguous, or is it necessary to say that whole thing?

Comment: I've just asked the follow-up question [Will these equations give me the approximate apparent RA and Dec using positions from Horizons?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27472/12102)